# SeleniumBasic VBA TakeScreenshot Element outside of the screenshot Error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the latest SeleniumBasic from https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic v2.0.9.
I'm having an issue with taking a screenshot for a specific element.

```
Dim bot As ChromeDriver
Set bot = New ChromeDriver
bot.AddArgument "--headless"
bot.AddArgument "--disable-extensions"

bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", "C:\temp"
bot.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
bot.SetPreference "download.prompt_for_download", False
bot.SetPreference "safebrowsing.enabled", True
bot.SetPreference "plugins.plugins_disabled", Array("Chrome PDF Viewer")

bot.Start "chrome"
bot.Get "https://mywebsite.com/somepage/1234"

'Take screenshot of a WebElement
Dim img As Image
Set img = bot.FindElementById("myGraph").TakeScreenshot() 
'TakeScreenshot method returns an Image object when used on a WebElement object.
img.SaveAs "C:\temp\mygraph.png"
```

When I run this, I get this error - Element outside of the screenshot

Looking at the Examples page from the GitHub repo, I'm using the exact same code that was provided by example and even the example has the same "Element outside of the screenshot" issue.

Anyone know how to resolve this or properly take a screenshot of a WebElement (not the entire web page).

Comment: I'm not sure I have seen a working example of that for vba. Worst case is write some js to scroll element to a specific point and use zoom and see if that works?

Comment: QHarr, thank for you for comment. I just realized what the error means. It means that the current element is not in view for the screenshot to work.

Answer (score 4):

Element Outside of the Screenshot error means the element is not in view of the browser.
You'll need to scroll the page to the element and then call TakeScreenshot.

Solution -

```
'Take screenshot of a WebElement
Dim img As Image
Set img = bot.FindElementById("myGraph").ScrollIntoView().TakeScreenshot() 
'TakeScreenshot method returns an Image object when used on a WebElement object.
img.SaveAs "C:\temp\mygraph.png"
```